# don't work edit spring mvc crud jdbctemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, crud, derby, jdbctemplate

this is the FabricanteEditController:

```
package Controller;

import Modelo.Conectar;
import Modelo.Fabricante;
import Modelo.FabricanteValidar;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
*
* @author x2010s
*/

@Controller
@RequestMapping("fabricanteedit.htm")
public class FabricanteEditController {

FabricanteValidar fabricanteValidar;
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

public FabricanteEditController() 
{
   this.fabricanteValidar=new FabricanteValidar();
   Conectar con=new Conectar();
   this.jdbcTemplate=new JdbcTemplate(con.conectar() );
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView form(HttpServletRequest request)
{
    ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
    int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    Fabricante datos=this.selectFabricante(id);
    mav.setViewName("fabricanteedit");
    mav.addObject("fabricante",new  Fabricante(id,datos.getNombre(),datos.getDireccion(),datos.getTelefono(),datos.getTipo()));
    return mav;
}

 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView form
    (
            @ModelAttribute("fabricante") Fabricante f,
            BindingResult result,
            SessionStatus status,
            HttpServletRequest request
    )
{
 this.fabricanteValidar.validate(f, result);
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
         ModelAndView mav=new ModelAndView();
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        Fabricante datos=this.selectFabricante(id);
        mav.setViewName("fabricanteedit");
        mav.addObject("fabricante",new Fabricante(id,datos.getNombre(),datos.getDireccion(),datos.getTelefono(),datos.getTipo()));
        return mav;
    }else
    {
        int id=Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
                "update fabricante "
            + "set nombre=?,"
            + "direccion=?,"
            + "telefono=? "
            + "tipo=? "
            + "where "
            + "id=? ",
     f.getNombre(),f.getDireccion(),f.getTelefono(),f.getTipo(),id);
     return new ModelAndView("redirect:/fabricante.htm");
    }   

}
    public Fabricante selectFabricante(int id) 
{
    final Fabricante maker = new Fabricante();
    String quer = "SELECT * FROM fabricante WHERE id="+id;
    return (Fabricante) jdbcTemplate.query
    (
            quer, new ResultSetExtractor<Fabricante>() 
        {
            public Fabricante extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    maker.setNombre(rs.getString("nombre"));
                    maker.setDireccion(rs.getString("direccion"));
                    maker.setTelefono(rs.getString("telefono"));
                    maker.setTipo(rs.getString("tipo"));

                }
                return maker;
            }


        }
    );
    }
}
```

this is the view fabricanteedit.jsp

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"   %>
<%@taglib  prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Editar Fabricante</title>
    <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a href="<c:url value="/fabricante.htm" />">Listado de  fabricante</a></li>
            <li class="active">Editar</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Editar</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                    <form:form method="post" commandName="fabricante">
                        <h1>Complete el formulario</h1>

                        <form:errors path="*" element="div"  cssClass="alert alert-danger" />

                       <p>
                            <form:label path="nombre">Nombre:  </form:label>
                            <form:input path="nombre" cssClass="form-control" />

                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <form:label  path="direccion">Direccion</form:label>
                            <form:input path="direccion" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <form:label path="telefono">Telefono</form:label>
                            <form:input path="telefono" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </p>

                        <p>
                            <form:label path="tipo">Tipo</form:label>
                            <form:input path="tipo" cssClass="form-control" />
                        </p>

                        <hr />
                        <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-danger" />
                    </form:form>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </body>
```

my database is derby.

when trying to edit a manufacturer, the following error occurs:

HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error

type Exception report

messageInternal Server Error

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update fabricante set nombre=?,direccion=?,telefono=?, tipo=?, where id=? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 64.

root cause

org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [update fabricante set nombre=?,direccion=?,telefono=?, tipo=?, where id=? ]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 64.

root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 64.

root cause

ERROR 42X01: Error de sintaxis: Encountered "where" at line 1, column 64.

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something meaningful. All you've done is repeat the information that is already available in the tags. Your title should describe a problem or ask a question in a way that will have some meaning to a future reader here looking at a list of search results. Repeating tag information is meaningless and useless. Please spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages, particularly [ask].

Answer (score 0):

In your code in your question, you show:

```
    this.jdbcTemplate.update(
            "update fabricante "
        + "set nombre=?,"
        + "direccion=?,"
        + "telefono=? "
        + "tipo=? "
        + "where "
        + "id=? ",
```

In the error message that you quote in your question, you show:

```
bad SQL grammar [update fabricante set nombre=?,direccion=?,telefono=?, tipo=?, where id=? ];
```

Both of these look wrong to me.

In the code that you show, you are **missing** a comma after `"telefono=? "`.

In the error message that you show, you have an **extra** comma after `tipo=?,`

It is very confusing that these two things do not match up.

But I believe **both** are incorrect. You should have a comma in between each `column=?` expression, and no comma after the last column before the `where`.

I believe that if you very closely inspect your program, looking at the placement of the commas in your `update` statement, you will find the problem.